# Angular Filter find string in multiple array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array like this:

```js
const arr = [
  {
      groupname:'xyz',
      members:[{
        0: "alex",
        1: "john"
      }]
  },
  {
    groupname:'abc',
      members:[{
        0: "khalifa",
        1: "julia"
      }]
  }
];
```

I need to filter the `members` array. For example, within the members array, I need to get only the entires with the `julia`.

I tried like this but its showing empty array.

```
this.groups.filter(x => x.members === this.membername)
```

Comment: can you post expected result?

Comment: Combine https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/215552 with https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/215552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array.find() with the nested object. Also your JSON is not valid , kindly check the below example

```js
let  myarray = [
  {
    "groupname": "xyz",
    "members": [
      "alex",
      "john"
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupname": "abc",
    "members": [
      "khalifa",
      "julia"
    ]
  }
];
let result = myarray.filter(x => x.members.find((a)=> a === "julia"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It’s not JSON even in your example. JSON is a text format.

Comment: You misunderstand; there is no JSON in the question or this answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do by this

```
let result = myarray.filter(x => x.members.find((a)=> a === "here put the string));
```

Answer (score 1):

You listed your members as array  that containing an array.

Change your array to :

```
   const arr = [
        {groupname:'xyz', members:[ "alex", "john"]},
        {groupname:'abc',members:["khalifa","julia"]}
      ];
```

and the logic function will be :

```
this.arr.filter(x => x.members.some((a)=> a === name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution since `members` is an array of objects but should be just an array...

```js
const search = 'julia';

function filterArr(arr) {
  for (const entry of arr) {
    if (entry.members.every((elem) => Object.values(elem).includes(search))) {
      return entry;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  {
      groupname:'xyz',
      members:[{
        0: "alex",
        1: "john"
      }]
  },
  {
    groupname:'abc',
      members:[{
        0: "khalifa",
        1: "julia"
      }]
  }
];

console.log(getEntity('julia'))

function getEntity(searchString) {
  let result;
  arr.forEach(val => {
  val.members.forEach(val1 => {
    Object.values(val1).forEach(val2 => {
      if (val2 === searchString) {
        result = val;
      }
    });
  });
});
return result;
}
```

please try this